# How to add blur effect into UIImage with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiblureffect

I'd like to add blur effect in UIimage, not UIImage View. 
I can add blur effect into uiimage view
just like this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = img.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
img.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

But, I really want to add into uiimage. Because I have to draw image with text. so here is my function:

```
func textToImageWithPhoto(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {  

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize.init(width: 375, height: 375), false, scale)

    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -100), size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 375*1.5)))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 187.5 - 150/2 ), size: CGSize.init(width: 375, height: 375))
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.saveData(img: newImage!, text: self.quotesTxt.text!) //SAVE CORE DATA

    return newImage!
}
```

And is there some way to add blur effect within draw function?

Comment: Visite here [blurring & tinting image]((https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013396-UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h-DontLinkElementID_8)

Comment: After adding text on your image  while returning new image do this before  `blurredImage = UIImageEffects.imageByApplyingLightEffect(to: newImage)`

Comment: @Mukesh Thanks! But, when I add blur image, image size is changed! I'd like to keep image size. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIIMageView {

    func addBlurEffect(){
        //if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {

            GlobalData.effectView.frame = self.bounds
            GlobalData.effectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]
            self.addSubview(GlobalData.effectView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                GlobalData.effectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
            })
        //}

    }

    func removeBlurEffect(){
        for subView in self.subviews{
            if subView is UIVisualEffectView{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    GlobalData.effectView.effect = nil
                }, completion: { (success:Bool) in
                    subView.removeFromSuperview()
                })

            }
        }

    }
```

Use this extension. it's work for me. I dont try but you can change extension type as UIImage maybe.

Comment: OP already mentioned that he don't want to add `blur effect` into `UIImageView`

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yup..that's right :(